# In Common Lisp (ClozureCL), what expression yields a value of type `(SIMPLE-ARRAY ARRAY (5 3 *))`?

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, type-systems, clozure-cl

I am trying to learn CL using ClozureCL and am in the middle of [Google's Lisp koans](https://github.com/google/lisp-koans/blob/master/koans/type-checking.lsp).

**Spoiler warning**: I'm giving away an answer to frame my question, because if I don't do so, submitted answers might not be as targeted.

---

The code here shows a value of `x` that passes.

```
(define-test test-guess-that-type!
  (let ((x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY ARRAY (5 3 *))))
    (assert-true (subtypep x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (* 3 *))))
    (assert-true (subtypep x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (5 * *))))
    (assert-true (subtypep x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY ARRAY *)))
    (assert-true (typep (make-array '(5 3 9) :element-type 'STRING ) x))
    (assert-true (typep (make-array '(5 3 33) :element-type 'VECTOR ) x))))
```

I didn't feel like I learned much though beyond the pattern used in type notation. I wanted to see if I can pass the test using a value of `x` in the form `(type-of ...)` so that I can relate actual values to types by example.

That said, here's my current uneducated guess. The assert I marked with `; <!>` is failing for my first chosen value for `x`.

```
(define-test test-guess-that-type!
  (let ((x (type-of (make-array '(5 3 33) :element-type 'VECTOR))))
    (assert-true (subtypep x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (* 3 *))))
    (assert-true (subtypep x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (5 * *))))
    (assert-true (subtypep x '(SIMPLE-ARRAY ARRAY *)))
    (assert-true (typep (make-array '(5 3 9) :element-type 'STRING ) x)) ; <!>
    (assert-true (typep (make-array '(5 3 33) :element-type 'VECTOR ) x))))
```

My question is: **If you are restricted to use of `(type-of <val>)` what `<val>` solves the koan**?

Observations thus far:

- Here, `(type-of x)` is `(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (5 3 33))`, which is obviously not what I want. I want `(SIMPLE-ARRAY ARRAY (5 3 *))` with vector elements.
- It appears I can only specify dimensions using `fixnum` values, and setting `:adjustable t` makes the array "expressly adjustable", which apparently means the array is no longer a `SIMPLE-ARRAY`.

Comment: `(type-of <some-array>)` will never return a type with `*` in the dimensions, it will always return the actual dimensions of the array.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. Sounds like "no solution" is the answer. Please add your answer and I'll accept it once SO's timer allows me to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a solution to this. Actually, it's possible that you might find a solution in some CL implementations, but there's no guarantee about it. The specification of [`TYPE-OF`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_tp_of.htm#type-of) doesn't go into detail about the type specifier returned in most cases, merely requiring that

```
(typep object (type-of object))
```

must be true, along with a few other retrictions. But there's nothing specific to arrays.

I don't think any implementations will ever return type specifiers containing `*` in the dimensions for an array type. They'll likely either return a very general type specifier that omits the dimensions entirely, or a very specific one that contains the actual dimensions of the given array.

Nothing prevents an implementation from returning a type specifier like the one you're looking for, but it would be pretty perverse. Given a 3-dimensional array, why would it specifically choose to make the last dimension unspecified rather than one or all of the others?

Comment: Appreciate this, +1. Will only change acceptance if someone shows contrary evidence. The koans are SBCL-focused if that helps contextualize things, but I doubt it changes things much.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't feel like I learned much though beyond the pattern used in type notation.

You might have learned a few things:

- Common Lisp has type declarations for multi-dimensional arrays with element types and specified dimensions and wild card dimensions.
- there are subtypes of these types and a function to check the subtype relationships (`SUBTYPEP`)
- there are simple arrays (not displaced, no fill-pointer, not expressly adjustable) and non-simple arrays
- the element type you pass to `MAKE-ARRAY` is not necessarily the element type of the created array (see the function `UPGRADED-ARRAY-ELEMENT-TYPE`)

*